# Post Publish Metaxbox on a Front End Page

Tags: posts

When I create a post within the Admin section in the top right there is a Publish meta box that you can chance the Status, Visibility and Publish date. I created a page to allow a user to create a post on the front end with a page. I would like to give them the same ability to use this functionality and since it's already built into Wordpress, is there a way to use this metabox in a front end page so I don't have to code that same functionality?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by front-end page, does this mean that instead of going to the admin panel they now modify the page from the front-end *view* ? If so you could take advantage of [`wp_transition_post_status()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_transition_post_status)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I created a page with a form to mimic the admin panel. So the user will go to something like `website.com/create-post`. I then use the `wp_insert_post` codex to insert the post into the database. I'd like the user to decide on the publish date, status etc and since that functionality is already built into the admin panel with that meta box, if I could just display that meta box I wouldn't have to code those same options into my form.